# Problem on Mac : "Can't find a register in class BREG while reloading asm"

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, gcc4

I tried to port some code onto Mac OS X.

The program uses the "ttmath" library, a header big-num header library.
This library works fine on both windows and linux, but when I try to compile and run it on a Mac, the following error message always shows up :

```
"can't find a register in class 'BREG' while reloading 'asm'".
```

I found some documents say that this problem is due to the old version of GCC compiler (build 5488), but this message still shows up after I updated GCC.

currently my GCC version is :

```
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5490)
```

and the OS is:
 Mac OS X version 10.5.8

I can't find any useful information about how to solve this problem, is there anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've seen this error when compiling non-PIC-safe assembly code with -fpic. Maybe Mac's gcc defaults to having that option on, and ttmath code is not PIC-safe? (More details about where exactly the error comes from would be helpful.)

Comment: You know, GCC has a version 4.5 now. Updating to 4.0.1 is still way old.

Comment: If you use the current Xcode (3.x) then you get gcc 4.2. I think this may require that you upgrade to OS X 10.6 though.

Comment: To vanza: Thanks! I tried to turn it off and it works !!! Now I just need to figure out how to specify this option in Qt Creator :)

Comment: To DeadMG: apple didn't provide gcc 4.3 or higher for MAC user yet.

To vanza: I use Xcode 3.1.3, but it still 4.0.1 >< I tried to download Xcode 3.2, but it only works for 10.6 or higher, anyway, thanks for your suggestion!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for DeadMG!
This problem is due to the PIC-safe option.

I added `"-mdynamic-no-pic"` and `"-fno-pic"` when I compile the code, and it works fine now :)