# How to call cpuid instruction in a Mac framework?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly, x86, cpuid

I want to use the cpuid instruction to identify features of an Intel CPU.  I found the cpuid.h header in Kernel.framework, so I added Kernel.framework to my project and included `<Kernel/i386/cpuid.h>` in my source file.  That produced

```
kern/kern_types.h: No such file or directory
```

which I don't understand. But the function `do_cpuid`, which is what I think I want to use, is defined inline, so I tried just copying that into my source.

```
static inline void
do_cpuid(uint32_t selector, uint32_t *data)
{
    asm("cpuid"
        : "=a" (data[0]),
          "=b" (data[1]),
          "=c" (data[2]),
          "=d" (data[3])
        : "a"(selector));
}
```

That gave me errors:

```
error: can't find a register in class 'BREG' while reloading 'asm'
error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
```

Googling that error led me to this question: [Problem on Mac : "Can't find a register in class BREG while reloading asm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010069/problem-on-mac-cant-find-a-register-in-class-breg-while-reloading-asm)

But the solution to that question was to use the dynamic-no-pic option (`GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC` build setting), and Xcode's help on build settings says "Not appropriate for shared libraries (which need to be position-independent)."  I'm building a framework, which I think counts as a shared library.  So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

This rather cryptic error message:

```
error: can't find a register in class 'BREG' while reloading 'asm'
error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
```

is occurring because one of the constraints isn't allowed. In this case it is `EBX`. When compiling 32 bit code with the `-fPIC` option (position independent code) the `EBX` register is used for relocation. It can't be used as an output or appear as a clobbered register.

Although most people suggest compiling with special compiler flags, the function can be rewritten to support *x86-64*/*IA32* and *PIC*/*non-PIC* by modifying the assembler code to save the `EBX` register itself and restore it after. This can be done with code like:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

static inline void
do_cpuid(uint32_t selector, uint32_t *data)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "xchg %%ebx, %k[tempreg]\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "xchg %%ebx, %k[tempreg]\n"
        : "=a" (data[0]),
          [tempreg]"=&r" (data[1]),
          "=c" (data[2]),
          "=d" (data[3])
        : "a"(selector),
          "c"(0));
}
```

The significant change is that the `data[1]` value will be returned in an available register the compiler chooses. The `=&r` constraint tells the compiler that whatever register it chooses can't be any of the other input registers (we early clobber the register with the `xchg` code). In the code we exchange `EBX` with available register the compiler chose. We then exchange it back afterward. When finished `EBX` will contain its original value and the free register that was chosen will contain what was returned by `CPUID`. The assembler template will then move the contents of that free register to `data[1]`.

Effectively we have circumvented the problem by allowing the compiler to choose a free register. The compiler is smart enough not to use `EBX` if it is tied up because it might be used for relocatable code. In 64 bit code `EBX` isn't used for relocation like it is with 32 bit code so it may be available for usage.

An astute observer might have noticed the `xor %%ecx,%%ecx`. This is a change I made independent of the `EBX` issue. It is now considered good practice to clear `ECX` because some processors made by AMD may return stale values if `ECX` is not zero. If you are developing for a non-PPC Mac platform only, this change isn't necessary since Apple uses Intel processors that don't exhibit such behavior.

Generally `EBX` is special in 32 bit relocatable/PIC code which is why the compiler originally complained with its cryptic message.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : at this point I'd just consider using the cpuid intrinsic.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : I tossed in the change.

Answer (score 1):

So, this might not answer the question but should provide an interesting enough workaround for at least some people finding their way here.

---

`sysctl` provides a lot of information about a machine's CPU on macOS. For starters type `man sysctl` in Terminal and look at everything prefixed with `machdep.cpu`. Take for example `feature_bits` as replacement for `uint64_t cpuid_features(void);` from `cpuid.h`:

`sysctl machdep.cpu.feature_bits` gives you the actual features bitmask, although not very readable.
`sysctl machdep.cpu.features` does the job a little better and provides you with mostly comprehensible acronyms.

Now, doing this programmatically is even more interesting and actually pretty feasible:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

// ...

int64_t value = 0;
size_t valueByteSize = sizeof(value);
int error = sysctlbyname("machdep.cpu.feature_bits", &value, &valueByteSize, NULL, 0);
if (!error)
{
   // Check for the next best bit defined in cpuid.h
   // Since you can't build with cpuid.h directly, just copy over the definitions you actually need
   bool hasFPU = value & CPUID_FEATURE_FPU;
}
```