# Which registers to use as temporaries when writing AMD64 SysV assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, abi

I'm implementing a function using `cpuid` in assembly according to AMD64 SysV ABI. I need 2 temporary registers to be used in the function itself: the first one to accumulate return value and the second one as a counter.

My function currently looks as:

```
;zero argument function
some_cpuid_fun:
  push rbx

  xor r10d, r10d ;counter initial value
  xor r11d, r11d ;return value accumulator initial value
  some_cpuid_fun_loop:
  ;...
  cpuid
  ;update r10d and r11d according to the result


  mov eax, r11d
  pop rbx
  ret
```

Since `cpuid` clobbers `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx` I cannot use them across different `cpuid` executions. As documented in the [`AMD64 SysV ABI`](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf):

```
r10    temporary register, used for passing a function’s
       static chain pointer

r11    temporary register
```

There is only one strictly temporary register `r11`, `r10` seems to have a different purpose (and its usage as a loop counter is not one, I obviously did not pass any static chain pointers).

***QUESTION:*** Is the `some_cpuid_fun` function implementation `AMD64 SysV ABI` compatible? If no how to rewrite it to stay compatible with the ABI?

Comment: If you are prepared to use `push` (as you have with rbx), then you can use essentially any of them.  BTW, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545972/2189500), you may need to zero rcx as well.

Comment: near duplicate of [Acceptability of regular usage of r10 and r11](//stackoverflow.com/q/49928950)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have identified all the registers used for the arguments, none in this case, all you have to care about is if a register is volatile (not preserved across calls) or not.

In short, looks at the last column of the Figure 3.4 (where the usage for `r10` come from): It is **not** preserved, so you can use it without restoring it.
The *Usage* column only tells you where to look for the arguments **if expected** and where to put the return value.
If you don't take a static chain pointer in input, you can overwrite `r10` as soon as needed.

So yes, using `r10` as a temporary register is ABI compatible.

For reference:

> This subsection discusses usage of each register. Registers %rbp, %rbx and
>   %r12 through %r15 “belong” to the calling function and the called function is
>   required to preserve their values. In other words, a called function must preserve
>   these registers’ values for its caller. Remaining registers “belong” to the called
>   function. 5 If a calling function wants to preserve such a register value across a
>   function call, it must save the value in its local stack frame.